# The POM for org.springframework.security:org.springframework.security.web:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE is missing, no dependency information available

Tags: spring, maven, dependencies, repository

When including into `pom.xml`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.springframework.security.web</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

with repositories

```
    <repository>
        <id>com.springsource.repository.bundles.milestone</id>
        <name>EBR Spring Milestone Repository</name>
        <url>http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/milestone</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>org.springframework.maven.milestone</id>
        <name>Maven Central Compatible Spring Milestone Repository</name>
        <url>http://maven.springframework.org/milestone</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>com.springsource.repository.bundles.release</id>
        <name>EBR Spring Release Repository</name>
        <url>http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/release</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>com.springsource.repository.bundles.external</id>
        <name>EBR External Release Repository</name>
        <url>http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/external</url>
    </repository>
```

I get the following error message when doing the maven build:

```
The POM for org.springframework.security:org.springframework.security.web:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE is missing, no dependency information available
```

Other spring libraries are included well. What's going wrong? Thank you for any help.

---

**Update**

I simplified `pom.xml` to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>test</groupId>
<artifactId>test</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<version>1.0.1</version>
<name>test</name>
<url>http://test</url>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.springframework.security.web</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>com.springsource.repository.bundles.milestone</id>
        <name>EBR Spring Milestone Repository</name>
        <url>http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/milestone</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>org.springframework.maven.milestone</id>
        <name>Maven Central Compatible Spring Milestone Repository</name>
        <url>http://maven.springframework.org/milestone</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>com.springsource.repository.bundles.release</id>
        <name>EBR Spring Release Repository</name>
        <url>http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/release</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>com.springsource.repository.bundles.external</id>
        <name>EBR External Release Repository</name>
        <url>http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/external</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
</project>
```

and when calling `mvn -U install` (forces update check) it gives

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project test: Could not resolve dependencies for project test:test:jar:1.0.1: Could not find artifact org.springframework.security:org.springframework.security.web:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE in com.springsource.repository.bundles.milestone (http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/milestone)
```

Comment: Why are you using all those non-standard repositories?

Comment: What is the standard repository so we can get rid off the others?

Comment: @Lars: Sean's answer has a link to it.

Comment: @Donal: I cannot extract the repository URL as it contains also the version number. Shall I just take `http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/` as the repository for all spring modules?

Comment: @Lars: Yes. Unless you've got a **very** unusual local configuration, you'll have the right repository by default too. This means you can (probably) just remove that `<repositories>` section.

Comment: @Donal: Thank you, I will try that repository. I was also wondering why we've got so many Spring repositories, I assume it dates back to the research work my colleagues have done.

Comment: @Lars: The rule of thumb I use is this: only put a repository in explicitly if you have to (e.g., because the code isn't in Central — irritatingly still the case for some things I use — or because it's your project's snapshot repo). I also try to avoid using snapshots if possible; too likely to have random temporary problems.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I see that [the repository](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/security/spring-security-web/3.0.5.RELEASE/) is properly populated, so the problem is a wrong artifactId. It's `spring-security-web`, not `org.springframework.security.web`.

Comment: So there's a wrong example out in http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/petclinic-tutorial.html that I was following. Thanks for pointing that out Donal! Interestingly `org.springframework.security.web` works well with version 3.0.3.RELEASE.

Comment: @Lars: You have to *really* watch it with the Spring documentation; it's full of these sorts of subtle errors. (Well, maybe not “full” but I've certainly hit a few in the past, enough that I don't trust it any more…)

Comment: The next thing is that the petclinic example is not working anymore. See my comment down at Sean's answer. Spring has gone, it's going to be summer now...

Answer (score 3):

You are using the wrong artifactId. Use this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

And you don't need any custom repositories, you can find it [in Maven Central](http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/security/spring-security-web/3.0.5.RELEASE/).

Answer (score 0):

http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/petclinic-tutorial.html gives a wrong artificact Id where I copied the dependency from. Interestingly it works with version 3.0.3.RELEASE but not with 3.0.5.RELEASE.

Thanks for the hint Sean, I updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks Sean, I updated my answer. The petclinic example doesn't work at all. Despite its wrong artifact Id for spring security someone has changed the trunk to a version that does not process static resources correctly anymore. But that's another topic.