# Stanford Topic Modeling Toolbox: not being able to compile with maven

Tags: java, scala, maven, stanford-nlp

I tried to compile the TMT toolkit source using maven as per the README file by invoking th command

```
mvn compile
```

However, since there is no pom.xml file in the project root directory, maven was unable to compile the project.

I also tried to use an empty pom.xml. Here is the error which I got:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]   The project  (/mnt/sdb2/software/stanford_tmt/pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Non-readable POM /mnt/sdb2/software/stanford_tmt/pom.xml: input contained no data
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
```

My question is: Have any of you encountered a similar problem? If so, then how did you resolve it? Is there a way to generate a pom.xml file given the scala source files?

Comment: Have you tried using an emty pom.xml file?

Comment: i did just now... edited the question to reflect the error...

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18732175/the-pom-for-project-is-missing-no-dependency-information-available ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a Scala project so you will need something like the pom.xml file in the [source distribution for v0.2.1](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/tmt/tmt-0.2/).